# Are finitely additive measures 'topological'?

Tags: measure-theory, category-theory

The category of measurable spaces are 
[topological](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category) over $Set$ in that they support initial & final structures similarly to that topological spaces.

A measurable space is a set supporting $\sigma$ - algebras. If we forget the $\sigma$ structure, and so only have closure under finite meets & unions does the category remain topological over $Set$.

It seems to me that they should since the lattice of such algebras on a space is complete.

Comment: Are you asking whether the category of measurable spaces is topological over the category of (distributive) lattices?
Or, that the finitely measurable spaces is topological over $Set$?

Comment: Over $Set$. I'll edit the question.